# Getting an error message - "java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.simpleConcat(StringConcatHelper.java:421)"

Tags: java, string, algorithm, data-structures, stack-overflow

Hello Guys I was making a program of "Generate all parenthesis" and I got the error message as:-***"java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.simpleConcat(StringConcatHelper.java:421)"***

along with this I am getting error of stack overflow

I am attaching a code with this error please see to it and tell me the modification if needed:-

```
public class j{
public static void main(String[] args){
    int n = 2;
    int open = n;
    int close = n;
    String op = " ";
    findAns(op, open, close);
}
private static void findAns(String op, int open, int close){
    if (open == 0 && close == 0){
        System.out.println(op);
    }
    
    if (open == close){
        String op1 = op + "(";
        findAns(op1, open - 1, close);
        return;
    }
    if (open != 0){
        String op1 = op + "(";
        open = open - 1;
        findAns(op1, open, close);
    }
    String op1 = op + ")";
    close = close - 1;
    findAns(op1, open, close);
    return;
}   }
```

Comment: That is not the error message, that is a stackframe from the stacktrace. Post the **entire** stacktrace.

Comment: Well, it's a stack overflow anyway.  It's happening because your recursive calls never terminate.

Comment: Sir can you please suggest me where I am going wrong!

Comment: Did you try debugging your code? By doing so you can clearly see where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an exit condition for your recursion.  Maybe this?

```
if (open == 0 && close == 0){
    System.out.println(op);
--> return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir it worked but 1 problem is that it is not giving me desired output can you please suggest me :-  (()) , ()) - > output that I am getting and real output is:- (()), ()()

Comment: @Varun Also add a return statement in the third if-block and you should get your desired output

Comment: @Varun:  Keep troubleshooting.  You're doing great.

Comment: Sir I have been trying since 2 hours I am not able to figure it out please suggest me sir! I am new to recursion

Comment: Ok I got it and it worked just modified my logic a bit and it worked thanks by the way!